# unable to load dashboard page after login successful in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, xajax

I have created a controller admin.php, when i am trying to load the dashboard page which is written in dashboard() method, it giving me page not found error.
please help me i am new to codeigniter.

This is controller : admin.php

```
<?php 

class admin extends CI_Controller
{

public function __construct()
{        

    parent::__construct();                  
    $this->xajax->register(XAJAX_FUNCTION,array('loginSubmit',&$this,'loginSubmit'));
$this->xajax->processRequest();
}
function index()
{
    $template['xajax_js'] = $this->xajax->getJavascript(base_url('xajax_js'));
    $this->load->view('admin/index',$template);
    //$this->dashboard();
} 

public function loginSubmit($formData)
{
    foreach($formData as $id=>$field)
    {
        $_POST[$id]=$field;
    }
    $objResponse=new xajaxResponse();   
    $loginData['username']=$this->input->post('uname');
    $loginData['password']=$this->input->post('password');
    $response=$this->munafa_model->login($loginData);
    if($response)
    {

        //$this->dashboard();
        $objResponse->alert("login");
        //$objResponse->redirect("admin/dashboard");
        $objResponse->script("window.location='admin/dashboard'");
    }
    else
    {
        $objResponse->alert("Invalid Login Credentials.");
        $objResponse->script("window.location.reload();");
    }
    return $objResponse;
}
public function dashboard()
{
    $template['xajax_js'] = $this->xajax->getJavascript(base_url('xajax_js'));
    $this->load->view('admin/header');
    $this->load->view('admin/dashboard',$template);
    $this->load->view('admin/footer');
}
}
?>
```

the dashboard function are working when it called to index method, but its not working after login successful. 
the else part of loginsubmit method is executing, and returning the message also from if part, only the page not redirecting, it gives the page not found error.

The Method of Model

```
public function login($loginData)
{
    $table_name="admin_login as al";
    $this->db->where('al.username',$loginData['username']);
    $this->db->where('al.password',$loginData['password']);
    $this->db->select('al.*')->from($table_name);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows==0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        $row=$query->row();
        $this->setSessionData($row);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your redirection is pointing to the correct place?

```
$objResponse->script("window.location='admin/dashboard'");
```

Add the SITE_URL to this, to see if this fixes it (you'll need the URL helper loaded);

```
$objResponse->script("window.location='" . site_url('admin/dashboard') . "'");
```